# How to add the missed or overridden migration changes to Snapshot in EF Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have made some changes to an Entity, added migration and run `Update-Database`. Then I pull the code and by mistake didn't take my changes in Snapshot. Now, what is the best way to get my changes for this particular migration?

I'm thinking to run `Update-Database <One Previous Migration>` and then run `Add-Migration` and then again `Update-Database`.

Is there any drawback or disadvantage in this approach? Or is there any better approach for this particular case?

Comment: That's a correct approach.

Comment: Upvote if u like my approach